# How to restrict Microsoft Graph to update only users of a certain group?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm new to Microsoft Graph, but like to use the API to let new users activate their accounts and let them set their passwords.

Pre-condition: The account is known in Azure AD.

Steps:

1. We let the user enter an "activation code"
2. If the code is recognized:
3. our application sets an initial password for the account (using Graph API)
4. our application logs the user in into his account
5. our application redirects the user to a password reset page
6. user sets a password of their choice

Question: The Graph API will be running under some sys-account. How do we restrict this sys-account, so the API can only be used to update the accounts of regular users? It may not be able to update system accounts or service accounts. What will be the best way to achieve this? In Azure AD I guess?

Also, will this work? Any security risks?

Thanks in advance for you help!